# How to record these moves?

Tags: notation, queens

Suppose a complete hypothetical positions that white has 6 queens and they are at a1, a4, a7, g1, g4, g7, respectively. How to record the following move in the standard algebraic notation?

1. Moving the first queen to d4?
2. Moving the second queen to d4?
3. Moving the third queen to d4?
4. Moving the fourth queen to d4?
5. Moving the fifth queen to d4?
6. Moving the sixth queen to d4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See for yourself: https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/3K4/q5q1/8/8/q5q1/8/8/q2Bk1q1_b_-_-

It's Qa1d4 for total unambiguity. I imagine this corner case is not covered by every PGN reader though.

1. Qa1d4
2. Qa4d4
3. Qa7d4
4. Qg1d4
5. Qg4d4
6. Qg7d4

Comment: Perfectlz correct. This is covered in the FIDE Laws of Chess Appendix C.10 https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf